# Autocomplete search bar using Google Places API in a fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

My app currently looks like this:

[image]

I want to add a search bar where I can search any place as Google maps. The search bar should be in an Auto Complete way.I got this code from https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/

Have a look at the above link.
And these codes where for an ORDINARY APP to get Auto Complete search bar. It doesnt suit  for app using fragment. And I dont know how to do it with fragments.
Here is my code

**For the Main Activity (ProfileActivity)**

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();


BottomBar mBottomBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
    mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu_user, new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int i) {
            if(i == R.id.ButtonBarFeed)
            {
                NewsFragment f = new NewsFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,f).commit();
            }
            else if(i == R.id.ButtonBarMap)
            {
                MapFragment f = new MapFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,f).commit();
            }
            else if(i == R.id.ButtonBarUser)
            {
                UserFragment f = new UserFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,f).commit();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {

        }
    });
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0,"#28809f");
}
public boolean googleServicesAvailable(){
    GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int isAvailable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        return true;
    }else if(api.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)){
        Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isAvailable, 0);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Can't connet to Play Services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return false;


}


boolean twice;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Log.d(TAG, "click");

    if(twice == true){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    twice = true;
    Log.d(TAG, "twice:" + twice);

    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Please press BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            twice = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "twice:" + twice);

        }
    }, 3000);

}
}
```

**MapFragment**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    SupportMapFragment fragment =  (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView1);
    fragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){

 }
 }
```

I have to add a search bar with Auto Complete like Google map.Please with reference of the Link which I have given at starting, Can Anyone code for my MapFragment?